# Serving React app with Flask fails with static files

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I am trying to do a very simple thing, serve a react app with Flask, but all the suggestions in other threads doesn't really work and it's becoming frustrating.

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

---

```
client
      build
           static
           index.html
```

So all JS/CSS files are in the static directory. I followed the usual advice and come up with this:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../client/build')

@app.route("/")
def serve():
    """serves React App"""
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, "index.html")

@app.route("/static/<path:path>")
def static_proxy(path):
    """static folder serve"""
    file_name = path.split("/")[-1]
    dir_name = os.path.join(app.static_folder, "/".join(path.split("/")[:-1]))
    return send_from_directory(dir_name, file_name)
```

and with that, it does serve index.html from the build directory when I open the root url. However, the trouble comes when the index.html loads, because all the static files are references like this `static/js/file.js`, that translates into GET request - `localhost/static/js/file.js`, and could not be found. I figured out that in order to hit `static/js/file.js` successfully, I would need to use this url `localhost/build/static/js/file.js`.

So, I in order to access static files, I would have to add the `build` prefix everywhere. Is there a better way to solve this ?

Comment: Have you tried some of the built in utility functions like [`send_static_file`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Blueprint.send_static_file) or [`url_for('static'...`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/)?

Comment: couldn't figure out how to solve the issue with those two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many attempts and trying different options, I gave up on solving this with Flask. I found that I could just build the react app like this

> export PUBLIC_URL=/build
>
> npm run build

to produce all references to have the path that flask expects (build/static/*)